# Manipulate columns using awk or sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a file which i would like to rearrange....

Input file:

```
sublat
16 0.04 0.051
32 0.04 0.050
16 0.06 0.055
32 0.06 0.054
c2dotc2
16 0.04 0.464
32 0.04 0.624
16 0.06 0.505 
32 0.06 0.743
```

Output file:

```
 A      B    sublat   c2dotc2

 0.04   16   0.051    0.464
 0.04   32   0.050    0.624    

 0.06   16   0.055    0.624 
 0.06   32   0.054    0.743
```

How do I achieve this using awk, sed?

Comment: Why "using awk, sed" specifically? Do you already have a partly-working solution in one of those languages?

Comment: no, i just thought that awk or sed are specifically used for this kind  of file manipulation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this awk script works for your requirement:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t";h="A\tB"}
    NF==1{h=h OFS $0;next}
    {x=$2OFS$1;r[x]=!r[x]?$3:r[x]OFS$3}
    END{print h;n=asorti(r,d);for(i=1;i<=n;i++)print d[i],r[d[i]]}' file
```

test with your data:

```
kent$  cat file
sublat
16 0.04 0.051
32 0.04 0.050
16 0.06 0.055
32 0.06 0.054
c2dotc2
16 0.04 0.464
32 0.04 0.624
16 0.06 0.505 
32 0.06 0.743

kent$  awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t";h="A\tB"}
        NF==1{h=h OFS $0;next}
        {x=$2OFS$1;r[x]=!r[x]?$3:r[x]OFS$3}
        END{print h;n=asorti(r,d);for(i=1;i<=n;i++)print d[i],r[d[i]]}' file
A       B       sublat  c2dotc2
0.04    16      0.051   0.464
0.04    32      0.050   0.624
0.06    16      0.055   0.505
0.06    32      0.054   0.743
```

Comment: Thank you so much.... But when I have bigger numbers, for ex. if sublat corresponding to A=0.06, B=32 was, say 1000.345, then the whole column is shifted and the headings of the column dont match. How can i rectify this? Thankyou sooo much for your time!

Comment: if you meant the "shift problem" is just format thing, try to pipe the output to `column -t`. it looks like `awk '......' file|column -t`